# Can't remove index.php on CodeIgniter2.1.2 with RHEL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url, indexing

I have followed from many links to solve this problem. However, It doesn't work with my project.

1. Move `.htaccess` file to CI root directory
2. Config about `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess` file (all structures that I found on the Google)
3. change `config[‘index_page’]` to an empty
4. Set `config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI' or 'QUERY_STRING'`
5. then, it shown

> Not Found   The requested URL /class/method was not found on this
>   server.

I don't know how to fixed it further. I spent so long time for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install a fresh copy of CodeIgniter
2. Change `$config['index_page']` to `= '';`
3. Copy this to your `.htaccess`

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Visit `http://yourhost/codeigniter/welcome/index`.

Does it work? If not, change the last line of the `.htaccess` above to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

If it does not work at this point, check if your Apache supports mod_rewrite and it is enabled.

Comment: I already try with your solution but it's still not work.
How's different between both last line of your advice. It's the same. ;) 
In additional, Can you please tell me how to check mod_rewrite on Apache. I can't find its directory. Thanks so much

Comment: I'm really sorry, I've edited the line, you can try now. To check if mod_rewrite works, try searching for it on google or here, on SO, for example, here is a nice topic: http://lynnepope.net/check-if-mod_rewrite-enabled-on-server

Comment: Yeahhhh !! Finally, I success to config it. Thank you so much. Your ref helped me a lot. :))

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled: If you're running Ubuntu open a terminal and type `sudo a2enmod rewrite`.

Furthermore, ensure that your `.htaccess` file is even being parsed. Again, on Ubuntu locate: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and modify the `<Directory>` directive to:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

Google search to find related Windows/Mac commands and file locations.